# Pandas: remove duplicates from a Dataframe where lots of numbers are duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I'm trying to go:
[From this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHweM.png) --> [to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BytDR.png)

input

[image: From this]

output

[image: to this]

I am editing this to try and explain better. I have a dataframe with two columns (let's call themm A and B). The Column B has a number from 0-8, abut will often be repeated in succession with each entry of the dataframe. e.g. 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 6, 6. In this example I would like to drop most of the rows so that column B would only read 0, 2, 8, 6.

I thought I could use drop_duplicates. However because all the rows contain a number from 0-8 they are all duplicated, all the rows are dropped. I hope I have explained better this time.

Comment: try this--> df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', subset= ['column_name'])

Comment: Please, try building a better description of your problem so we can understanding it correctly. Here is a simple guide to take you through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've rephrased it to try and explain it better

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = df[df[1]!=df.shift(-1)[1]]
```

This will keep all rows where the value in the second column is different from the value from the previous row. Or in other words, it will drop all rows that have the same value in the second column as the row before

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly you just want to use `unique`

```
newColA = df['colA'].unique()
newColB = df['colB'].unique()

new_df = pd.DataFrame([newColA, newColB]).T
```

there are better solutions, but I guess you're looking for something easy to understanding ;)